# How to make your player invincible / undetectable by zombies?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Ok, I want my character to either be ignored by zombies or unable to die (invincible). I've tried:

- Adding a health scoreboard but this is uneditable
- A repeating command block that gives the player instant health

  ```
  effect give @a[scores={ifBeast=1..}] minecraft:instant_health 1 10
  ```
- Making the player invisible (If you get close to the zombies they chase you)

None of the above work. The option that I would prefer is for the Zombies to completely **ignore** the player, but if I must resort to them being invincible to zombies while still getting hit (irritating) then I will accept that.

Comment: I might just have got this. I'm considering adding a "team" element.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create a team:

```
1.13+: /team add friendly
1.12-: /scoreboard teams add friendly
```

Join the team:

```
1.13+: /team join friendly
1.12-: /scoreboard teams join friendly
```

On a clock, make all zombies join the team:

```
1.13+: /team join friendly @e[type=zombie]
1.10-: /scoreboard teams join friendly @e[type=Zombie]
```

Mobs in the same team as you will not attack you.

Comment: Yep works perfectly thanks. (Will accept in 8 minutes)

Comment: Did you forget to set `friendlyFire` to `true`, or do you not need to?