# How do I add mobs to a team and make them passive to me?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How can I add certain mobs to a team and make them passive to me if they would normally attack me? I know how to do it in 1.8, but how can I do it now in 1.16.4?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! I have edited your question so it more meets the format of this site. Check it out!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make your player invincible / undetectable by zombies?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/301395/how-to-make-your-player-invincible-undetectable-by-zombies)

Comment: That thread proved unsuccessful, as I was still being attacked by the mob (i.e. zombies) after trying the things in that thread