# How to make mobs passive to you through commands in 1.16.4

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I know you could do this with the scoreboard in 1.8 and with teams in 1.13+, but when I use the regular methods mobs are still hostile towards me. Any alternatives? Plugins work too.

Comment: You asked [the same question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/379049/250180) before. Please do not re-ask questions.

Comment: Your already asked this question before, and it was closed: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/379049/how-do-i-add-mobs-to-a-team-and-make-them-passive-to-me