# Is there anyway to make mobs not attack you while playing in survival mode in minecraft edu?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-education-edition

Me and my friend are building some type of a RPG game in Minecraft: Education Edition and we were trying to figure out how to make mobs nonhostile while in survival and in normal mode.

I searched up commands and stuff like that but nothing worked.

I had tried the `/scoreboard teams` command as well, but yet, it didnt work either cause you cant use the team part in edu

any help here?

Comment: DO you mind using Peaceful Mode? That would make mobs not attack you.

Comment: @Potterton I cant use peaceful mode cause we just want one person to not get attacked due to the rules of the game we are making. So If we use peaceful mode, it will get rid of all the hostile mobs in the server. We want to keep them in if that explains it more. We just dont want them to attack one certain person.

Comment: Identical question for Java Edition: [How to make your player invincible / undetectable by zombies?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/301395/how-to-make-your-player-invincible-undetectable-by-zombies)

Answer (score -1):

If you use the command */effect |player name| resistance |period of time| 5 true* you can make that person invincible.

Comment: They mentioned that they needed mobs to be non-hostile, not simply that they didn't want to die.

Comment: I didn't say that it was a perfect solution.